# Make button width 100%, MVC 5 Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to learning bootstrap and loving it! However I cannot seem to find an easy guide to edit the massive bootstrap.css for custom items, such as a button.

What I want to do is expand my "Create" so that it fills the entire table row it is currently on.

- For reference: All my Models, Controllers, and Views were auto-generated and this is an *Index* page

Code for my Edit View, I am trying to make the **create** button at the top 100% across the top of the table.

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Entities.Employee>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Employees</h3>
    </div>

        <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" id="CreateButton">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create")';return false;">Create</button>
        </div>


    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Birthday)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Birthday)
                </td>
                <td>

                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the actual page currently as is.
[image]

If anyone could explain where you are inserting this code/css I would be eternally grateful as my guess and check method within `bootstrap.css` isn't working. haha

Thank you!

Comment: use the grid, `<div class='row'><div class='col-xs-12'><!-- button here --></div></div>`

Comment: Never edit any libraries files, unless you really know what your doing. most of the time your library files may become unstable &  would be tough to rectify any further errors

Comment: I agree with @dreamweiver. This isn't to say you can't override library code in external resources though.

Comment: well if you need to override your CSS , you can always add them on to your files or add them as a inline CSS like @James Donnely as suggested

Comment: @CarrieKendall the grid code doesn't seem to change anything? Do I need to order something differently?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This can be done with no extra style using [Bootstrap's grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) and the class [`btn-block`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-sizes).

```html
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Employees</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create")';return false;">Create</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <table class="table">
    <!-- ... -->
```

Here is a small [demo](http://jsbin.com/dikex/3/edit).

Comment: likewise with Carries comment, this does not seem to expand the button across the page

Comment: Ah thank you, it works awesomely! So I noticed I was starting to get to similar answer with guess and check, but you use btn-block rather than btn-group. Could you possibly shed some brief light on the difference for this?

Comment: `btn-group` implies more than one button. It's used for attaching buttons to one another horizontally (and also there's an aditional class for vertical attachment).

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this to your CSS:

```css
#CreateButton button {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This within Content -> bootstrap.css?

Comment: @Austin Put it in your own css file and link that after bootstrap.css in the html page, so it overrides any bootstrap styles.  That way you can update the bootstrap.css any time you like, without losing your changes.

Comment: @Archer Oh Okay, so how do I do that or can you point me to a resource? I am also new to MVC, C#, Visual, everything else I am using but I am catching on fast

Comment: @Austin I've not used MVC very much before, but I believe this may help: http://forums.asp.net/t/1978335.aspx?Where+to+define+JS+and+CSS+files+in+MVC5+for+Jquery+TAB+control+

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add any extra CSS (it shouldn't be something you're afraid to do, but as was stated in the comments of James' answer, it should be in a separate file), you can use the classes that exist in the bootstrap css file.

Carrie's answer is missing one step. You need the "col" class on the button as well:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success col-md-12" ...>Create</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The class provides `width: 100%;`. It provides what needs to be done. If they have another class that does the same thing, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @krillgar I shall definitely look into adding my own additional CSS files, thank you!

Comment: Good to hear. No matter what library you use, there is almost always going to be something that it doesn't cover that you want to use. Writing your own CSS will also allow you to learn WHY the library does what it does.

Comment: And what happens when the `display: block;` or any of the padding results in additional challenges to get it to display what I want? We'll have to add additional classes when all we're looking for is `width: 100%;`. The more you add to what your CSS does on a class, the harder it's going to be to get things to work everywhere you want it to. You've already wrapped it in a div, therefore it's going to display in block. The only additional feature that `btn-block` provides is the width. It doesn't matter which you pick.